# Update progressbar while heavy process

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I want to update a progressbar while executing a heavy process. Using swingutil invokelater dont works. It gets updated upon it's finished.

```
...long lasting command ..
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            searchDialog.setProgress( 60 );
          }
       });
...long lasting command ..
```

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix (a `SwingWorker` in this case). There is a [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25338142/418556)..

Comment: Use a `SwingWorker`, it has progress support via it's `PropertyChangeListener`, see [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125642/swingworker-in-another-swingworkers-done-method/23126410#23126410)

Comment: In the provided sample heavy work is done directly in the swingworker. I have a implemented a complex search with tree building and multiple threads. Would executing this search in the swingworker destroy my threadstructure?

Comment: @user2147674 SwingWorker is designated as bridge between WorkerThread and EDT (every methods expects doInBackground), doInBackground is place where can be invoked whatever you wrote about